# Passing XML between asp.net pages

Tags: asp.net, xml

I'm getting a XML as byte array, and what I'm looking to do is pass this between sequential pages. Basically in the XML I receive, it contains questions and answer choices for the user to choose from. This is generally going to be used to confirm the identity of a user.

Basically looks like this:

```
<questions>
 <question>
   <prompt>In which city is Fresno street?</prompt>
   <type>city.of.residence</type>
   <answer>HILLSIDE</answer>
   <answer>ATLANTA</answer>
   <answer>ALMO</answer>
   <answer>None of the above</answer>
 </question>
 <question>
   <prompt>In which state is Fresno street?</prompt>
   <type>city.of.residence</type>
   <answer>HILLSIDE</answer>
   <answer>ATLANTA</answer>
   <answer>ALMO</answer>
   <answer>None of the above</answer>
 </question>
</questions>
```

My general task is that upon the first page loading, retrieve this XML via HTTP Post then present the first question with answers, after answer is selected by user they hit a "next" button and the next question will appear from the xml for the user to answer.

The challenge is, how can I keep this XML persistent so that I can do my processing on it across multiple pages? Same thing with storing the answers they selected. When they've finished the quiz, I'll then need to send back the question type and answer in another HTTP Post so I'll need to keep track of the answers they user is selecting.

I'm new to asp.net development, and from my research came across a couple ideas but none of them pop out to me as being practical for my scenario.

Session variables almost sound like they would work, but our web application has a timeout period so the variables would end up getting lost and we have multiple web servers. The data in the XML could potentially be confidential, if it is don't think the idea of using a hidden field to store the values works, or does it?? So does that basically leave me with having to use a database? Only downside for me is the constant read/write transactions I'll need to perform for each page request.

Do any of y'all have a better approach or am I stuck using one of the options above? Thanks in advance for the insights.

Comment: Can you use localstorage? http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2011/01/12/asp-net-and-html5-local-storage

Answer (score 0):

You could store it in a session per user, which is secure and persistent between pages (although not necessarily persistent for long durations between visits, as the session may expire or the website may be reset.

Introduction to ASP.Net sessions for [WebForms](http://asp.net-tutorials.com/state/sessions/)

For longer term but still temporary persistence, store the session state in SQL Server, [using the state server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317604)

For permanent persistence, you will need to write the XML out to disk somehow - the easiest way would probably be to store it in an XML field in SQL Server once the question set has been fully answered.

Answer (score 0):

The post here describes 6 ways to pass data between pages.

http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/haissam/archive/2007/11/26/ways-to-pass-data-between-webforms.aspx

Some of the methods would require you convert the xml to a string.